# Replace element HTML faster in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am populating a list with about 25,000 items, using code like this:

```
var html = "";
for(var i = 0; i < reallyLongArray.length; i++) {
   html += "<li><a href='#'>Hi</a></li>";
}
$("#list ol").html(html);
```

Somewhat to my surprise, I used a profiler and found out that the bottleneck in my code was not the loop that iterated thousands of times, but setting the html of the list to the string. This usually takes about 5-10 seconds on my computer, which is an order of magnitude too slow.

Is there a way to do this that is significantly faster, i.e., at least 10 times faster?

Comment: What browser? Is there more than one element selected by `$("#list ol")`? Can you trade `reallyLongArray.length` for a constant number? Have you tried using the "stringbuffer" method instead of string concatenation?

Comment: Have you considered avoiding the option of adding tens of thousands of elements into the DOM, and instead load only smaller portions?

Comment: You are creating global variable `i`, better create it outside of the loop by prefixing it with `var` keyword. The `$("#list ol").html(html);` can also be replaced with `$("#list ol")[0].innerHTML = html;`

Comment: @Peter: So you're saying rendering is what is taking up the lion share of the time?

Comment: Also, you could try creating the elements in Javascript rather than in jQuery, which will be significantly faster. I don't have time to research out how to do this -- but I'm betting this will be your best option

Comment: @Matt No, only one element. I am not concerned about the speed of the string forming yet, as it is not prohibitively slow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wrap the html in a single item.  When jQuery builds elements from a string, it adds all top level items by iterating them.  If you wrap the list items in a single element, it should go much faster because it only has to add 1 top level element to the dom.

```
var html = "<ul>";
// your loop...
var html += "</ul>";
// add list html to list container
```

Comment: @PeterOlson: I suppose combining the answers from this thread will make for a super fast solution.  Great question btw.

Answer (score 5):

Aside from directly using `innerHTML`:

```
$("#list ol").get(0).innerHTML = html;
```

...and trying the "stringbuffer" technique:

```
var html = [];
for(i = 0; i < reallyLongArray.length; i++) {
   html.push("<li><a href='#'>Hi</a></li>");
}
$("#list ol").html(html.join(''));
```

...not really.

Comment: Was going to suggest that. `array.join()` will definitely speed up joining 25k items.

Answer (score 3):

Using DOM methods to create it should work faster:

```
var list = ("#list ol");
for(i = 0; i < reallyLongArray.length; i++) {
    $(document.createElement('li'))
        .append($(document.createElement('a'))
            .text('Hi')
            .attr({href: 'foobar'})
        )
        .appendTo(list);
}
```

**edit**: Actually, using DocumentFragment should make this even faster:

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for(i = 0; i < reallyLongArray.length; i++) {
    fragment.appendChild($(document.createElement('li'))
        .append($(document.createElement('a'))
            .text('Hi')
            .attr({href: 'foobar'})
        )
        .get(0)
    );
}
$('list ol').append(fragment);
```

You might also want to `clear()` the `<ol>` before adding the elements to it

**another edit** I've created a jsperf test at http://jsperf.com/insert-html-vs-dom-manipulation - both those versions are slower than setting the innerHTML (because jQuery is used to create the elements). Using dom maniuplation with native methods is much faster than setting the HTML, **BUT the fastest way, by a large margin, is using DOM manipulation with DocumentFragment without jQuery, using native methods**.

Comment: _"Using DOM methods to create it should work much faster"_ `[citation needed]`. [According to Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t03), **`innerHTML` is generally faster.**

Comment: @nwellcome I said `innerHTML` - nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: Appending a fragment is super-fast, but building the fragment or list one element at a time may well not be. In general I prefer the DOM-style methods because they are readable and safe against HTML injection attacks, but in the case where you're adding loads of nodes all at once, sometimes `innerHTML` can be faster.

Comment: See the [test](http://jsperf.com/insert-html-vs-dom-manipulation) I added to the answer. The fastest way is DOM manipulation with DocumentFragment, without using jQuery.

Comment: @bobnice http://jsperf.com/jquery-html-versus-appendchild/3, sheesh, you aren't kidding, using a fragment is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

This will speed it up by quite a bit.  String concatenation can take a long time when used a lot because of what happens "under the hood".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var html = new Array();
for(i = 0; i < reallyLongArray.length; i++) {
   html[i] = "<li><a href='#'>Hi</a></li>";
}
document.getElementById('list').getElementsByTagName('ol')[0].innerHTML = html.join("");

});
```

One thing to just note here, is that when doing an iteration of 25,000, it will be difficult to reduce the time down to milliseconds if you are inserting a large number of records.  This happens especially in IE as it parses each new element before inserting it.  Building a "pager" and caching the items you are going to insert will significantly speed that up.

Comment: String concatenation is not the bottleneck. The `html` function is.

Comment: @Kyle you edited since my comment. At any rate, you should use `html[i]` instead of `html[html.length]`...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I updated it to reflect that.  Yeah, I edited it because I noticed a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Array joins are faster than string manipulation.

```
var html[];

for(i = 0; i < reallyLongArray.length; i++) {
    html.push(string);
}
$(selector).html(html.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.grep(ComboBoxData, function (e) {

        if (e.Text.toLowerCase().indexOf(TextBox) != -1 || e.ID.toLowerCase().indexOf(TextBox) != -1) {

            Show = true;
            Result += "<li hdnTextID='" + hdTextID + "' onclick='Select(this," + TextBoxID + ")' onmouseover='triggerTheli(this)' HdntriggerID='" + e.HdntriggerID + "' postBack='" + e.TriggerPostBack + "' Event='" + e.EventName + "' HdnID='" + e.hdnID + "' SelectedValue='" + e.ID + "' style='background:" + Color + "'><a>" + e.Text + "<p> " + e.Description + " </p></a></li>";
            if (Color == "#eff3ec")
                Color = "#fff";
            else
                Color = "#eff3ec";
        }

    });
```

a good example of mine